# how to train a neural network in python to identify pattern of generating a number from a list

Tags: python, list, networking, numbers, identify

```
nums = ['2', '4', '1', '3', '9', '5', '1', '1', '5', '3', '6', '5', '9', '2', '3', '0', '4', '1', '6', '9', '8', '3', '0', '2', '2', '7', '0', '0', '6', '8', '8', '7', '9', '8', '6', '9', '8', '7', '0', '3', '0']

output_number = 3212448125
```

For example I have a huge dataset of these nums and output_numbers...is there any way I can train a neural network in python to identify if there is a pattern to get the number from the list?

So far I can't think of anyway

Comment: Yes, you need to supply your list of nums as input and your list of ouput_number as output to your network, and trained it. So the network will learn how to predict your output_number from you input. 

I need more details of how your numbers are to give you more specific features about the network.

Comment: The number is in a certain range, for example 1 to 10^9, also the number starts from either 2, 3, 8, or 9.

Comment: Didnt you have a list of numbers from 0-9? I see here you nums is a list of numbers 0-9

Comment: Is you output a sublist extract from the nums? I think you should provide a dataset

Comment: correct its a sublist extracted from the nums